# Who sells aviation fuel to airports?

Tags: airport, fuel

I want to ask about the jet fuel purchasing cycle. Is it the airport that buys the jet fuel from refineries and then sells it to the airlines? Or do airlines buy fuel directly from refineries?

Comment: At least at our local airport ([KGRB](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KGRB)), there are two FBO's that service the airlines. They purchase the fuel from wholesalers who truck it in, and then they have contracts with the airlines to refuel them. Larger airports have on-site tank farms and I believe they are owned by a fuel servicer that runs at the airport.

Comment: Airlines hedge against fuel price fluctuations in the financial markets, but buy the fuel locally at local prices. Both are not connected.

Comment: At the FedEx hub in Memphis there is an underground pipeline directly from the Valero refinery a few miles away

Answer (score 3):

The airport is buying fuel and selling to airlines. And more over, they provide different types of fuel on prior request by the airliner. Reference : [VCBI](http://www.airport.lk/AIS/PDF/A8.pdf)

Comment: This may be true in Sri Lanka but I would avoid making a blanket statement because its not the case in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Airlines make direct contracts with the major petrol companies eg Chevron, BP, etc. for large quantities of JET-A, often years in advance of its use.  It is the best way for them to buy fuel in bulk like that and it is traded much like stocks are.  Airports themselves will fuel airliners with on-hand supplies of JET-A and be reimbursed for it by the petrol companies.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Airlines have contracts either directly with say Shell or they have a contract with a 3rd party that handles their fueling requirements.

That 3rd party may or may not be the airport, it could be another company servicing the airport (and maybe others as well).

And such contracts may well differ depending on location. E.g. at their home base(s) they may draw directly from Shell, but at remote locations where Shell does not supply fuel to they may buy fuel from Joe's oil and lube supplies.